# Since the latest Windows 10 upgrade, my USB mouse stops and starts at random

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, power-management

On June 3rd, Windows 10 installed the Feature update version 1703.
Since then, my MS USB wheel mouse started to play up, disconnecting and reconnecting at random.
I followed the advice found in an old answer to the same problem, where it was suggested it was linked to Power Saving, Sure enough, switching off was enabled, which is silly, really, as I'm using a desktop PC with several monitors, wifi connections, etc.
After turning off the Power Saver option for all USB hubs, mouse and UI, I still found the mouse switched off and on at random. On at least one occasion, the device was also reinstalled automatically - with the power save switch and wake-up box reinstated. 
I have tried a non-MS mouse (Swann brand) which I plugged into different USB ports (USB 2 and 3), but that was also switched off at random.
In the end, I uninstalled the mouse completely and went back to the MS wheeler. Restarted the PC.
This may have fixed the problem - it's now been stable for half an hour. fingers crossed :)

Microsoft haven't replied yet.
All I can say is, the mouse had been working fine until the day after the Windows 10 update. It took me a while until I found this website, and the suggestion to check USB hubs' power management settings.

as a PS: The mouse has been well behaved all day today.

A big Thanks to Aaaaayu for https://superuser.com/posts/66467/revisions

It didn't last after all - back to start.
every few seconds, the device stop and device restart sounds chirp in the background. And the mouse cursor disappears. Even Solitaire becomes frustrating.

Comment: first things first - it was windows update that caused this? - what did Microsoft support answer was?

Comment: Uninstall your USB chipset drivers and let windows re-detect and re-install them.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it seems to have been fixed.
After Microsoft's latest Windows-10 update (dated 13 June) was delivered and installed, I haven't been able to reproduce the dropouts.

Easy to verify: Lifting the mouse and turning it upside-down would turn off the light; it no longer does.

Correction: the disconnect/reconnect music has restarted. And it is consistent across USB ports.
(still no answer from Microsoft either)

Answer (score 0):

To me, it would appear the you might be experiencing *interference* from other radio devices. Have you introduced new equipment into your environment? To your Laptop/Computer? Have you *moved* any of your equipment? This (your problem) can easily occur if channels of your wireless devices *overlap*. In those cases, the most powerful (radio signal) device wins.

I think the Windows update may just be a coincidence.

Answer (score -1):

was having the same problem. This worked for me:
1. Open device manager
2. click on Universal serial bus controllers
3. right click on each one
4. open power management window
5. check to see if the "allow this computer to turn off this device to save power" box is checked
6. uncheck the box and close the window.